# Where to ask about career paths from different degrees?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wanted to ask a question about whether taking a certain Dual Degree in Business Administration and Engineering (Bachelor's) was smart in terms of career paths.

So I tried to find a site where it would fit in nicely. I considered Careers, but as that isn't a Q&A site that was out of the question. So I ended up on Workplace where I knew they dealt with career choices, asking this question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/is-a-business-and-management-dual-degree-useful-in-the-real-world

It wasn't received well, so I assume I put it in the wrong place.
So where would it be better to put it?

Comment: Just realized this is the StackOverflow Meta, but when I try to go to meta.SE I come to the same site, so I assume this isn't just for StackOverflow?

Comment: Right, meta.SO is special in that it's both for SO and the SE network in general.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the answer is probably "nowhere on the SE network" without some serious editing of your question. As a general rule, questions that don't have definitive answers, but instead ask for opinions from other users, are considered to be not constructive (essentially off-topic) because there isn't a single correct answer to the question.

The text in the message saying the question has been closed really does cover it all quite well:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Questions which can only be answered with opinions, suggestions and advice are not welcomed anywhere on SE sites.

Check my answer on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156940/178982). We've discussed the fate of open-ended questions and as career advice is an open ended question, it may help.